# Doubly linked list visualization

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, algorithms

So, I was coding a doubly linked list & wanted to swap two adjacent nodes.

I was coding things like `node->next = node->next->next` and `node->next->prev = node` and it wasn't working out because I hadn't ordered the assignments correctly.

I was thinking to myself "wait, when you think of the next node, you mean the one that was originally next, before the swapping started ... BUT, you have already assigned `node->next` ..."

I am sure that we have all been there. I didn't want to introduce any temporary variables, so ended up surrounded by sheets of paper covered with boxes with arrows, crossed out and rejoined.

That got me to thinking how useful it would be to have some software which would let me graphically visualize each step of my linked list manipulation.

Perhaps something like [this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/QueueLL.html) (or [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/linked-list-visualization/5411857279221760)), but with a doubly linked list.

I realize that it is unlikely that such a beast exists, so will accept any operating system, <s>so long as the s/w is gratis</s> [Update: I will pay up to $25].

[image]